# How to use FBML outside canvas and iframe?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I want to render the `<fb:multi-friend-selector>` on my website. I have already registered my website for Application ID and Application Secret, and have successfully implemented the single-signon using the Facebook PHP SDK and javascript SDK. Since it has been written the javascript library must be intialized for xfbml and fbml to work, hence I have already done that with

FB.init({appId: 'config->facebook_settings->appid ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

It is placed just before the  tag. And all is working great with single signon thing, but it is only the other FBML markups that aren't rendering. Do these FBML only works in Canvas or, iframe or, anywhere.

---

Sorry I forgot to include this - I want to render this tag

Comment: Can you provide FBML that is not working? Are you dynamically adding FBML to the page or it is there from the beginning?

Comment: Hello Serg, No I am statically adding the tag at page load. Not using the javascript to insert that tag.

Comment: Some FBML tags (those that require being inside a serverFbml tag) only work in an IFRAME (which is the serverFbml tag is) or direct on a Canvas. I tried to find a good link, but Facebook documentaion seems as bad as ever.

Comment: So if I just add the following tag within iframe.. is it going to work ?

Comment: This has been written in example on the facebook for implementing  fb:multi-friend-selector tag - $facebook->require_frame(); I used it with my code and it throws error. It seems that it belongs to the Old reset API, but how can I call the same with new PHP SDK. Any clue...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb%3aserver-fbml-multi-friend-selector) how to use `fb:multi-friend-selector` outside of facebook. This would work if you don't add fbml after the page is loaded.